# Is there any API that I can call inside of the smartcontract that can get a transaction detail by txid?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm learning ethereum developing and want to check the transaction detail by txid in the smart contract, but I didn't find any interface that can help me to do that, anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to call `getTransaction`-like RPC call in smart contract. However, that's not possible.

All global variables which can be used in Solidity is following.

```
Global Variables

block.coinbase (address): current block miner’s address
block.difficulty (uint): current block difficulty
block.gaslimit (uint): current block gaslimit
block.number (uint): current block number
block.blockhash (function(uint) returns (bytes32)): hash of the given block - only works for 256 most recent blocks
block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp
msg.data (bytes): complete calldata
msg.gas (uint): remaining gas
msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)
msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message
now (uint): current block timestamp (alias for block.timestamp)
tx.gasprice (uint): gas price of the transaction
tx.origin (address): sender of the transaction (full call chain)
sha3(...) returns (bytes32): compute the Ethereum-SHA3 hash of the (tightly packed) arguments
sha256(...) returns (bytes32): compute the SHA256 hash of the (tightly packed) arguments
ripemd160(...) returns (bytes20): compute RIPEMD of 256 the (tightly packed) arguments
ecrecover(bytes32, uint8, bytes32, bytes32) returns (address): recover public key from elliptic curve signature
addmod(uint x, uint y, uint k) returns (uint): compute (x + y) % k where the addition is performed with arbitrary precision and does not wrap around at 2**256.
mulmod(uint x, uint y, uint k) returns (uint): compute (x * y) % k where the multiplication is performed with arbitrary precision and does not wrap around at 2**256.
this (current contract’s type): the current contract, explicitly convertible to address
super: the contract one level higher in the inheritance hierarchy
selfdestruct(address): destroy the current contract, sending its funds to the given address
.balance: balance of the address in Wei
.send(uint256) returns (bool): send given amount of Wei to address, returns false on failure.
```

Of course, there is some tricky solution which is using Oraclize.
I recommend to see this website :) https://docs.oraclize.it/

In conclusion, for your question, getting transaction detail from solidity is not possible in native-way, you should use offchain solution like Oraclize. :)

Answer (score 1):

Smart Contract only has the Access to the current state of the blockchain. Solidity is use to only creating the rules for the Transactions and updating the state of the variable. For getting the Transaction you have to use web3 libraray.